# system restarts while running a java web application in eclipse with tomcat server

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, windows-xp

When I run my java web application from eclipse using tomcat server, system gets restart. Its not even showing any exception or errors.

My system Configuration is,

- window xp sp3 32-bit
- JDK1.5.0
- eclipse helios
- tomcat server 6.0

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: you really need to provide more information on this, 64-bit? what JDK, OS?

Comment: Thanks for your reply and the system information  is window xp sp3 32-bit . JDK1.5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem may be either with your eclipse version or with the server or any code fragment which you are using. Try with fresh version of eclipse and server, if the problem still exists, check the system for any virus. If that also give negative check recently added code fragments..